# Android widget padding issue

Tags: android, widget, margin, padding, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm trying to clone a Power Management widgets from Sony Ericsson phones, but I'm having problems with the new ICS paddings for widgets.

I have read this article [link below], but I'm still having problems.

I ran my widgets on **GB** and it works just like I want it (the second one is the clone):
http://i.minus.com/iQmbhue0z0jJz.png

But while running in **ICS** my widget becomes smaller then the original one:
http://i.minus.com/iudmWwv6xBsxA.png

My files are:

---

**widget_info.xml** (@xml/widget_info.xml)

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40.0dip"
    android:minHeight="40.0dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

**widget.xml** (@layout/widget.xml)

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/widget1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/sms_disabled"
        android:clickable="true"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

---

I already tried to put `android:padding="0dp"` in ImageView, I already tried to put a layout on `widget.xml` and then put `android:padding="0dp"` on it, but I'm still having this issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Article: http://radleymarx.com/blog/app-widget-padding-margins-in-ics-android/ - I don't have 10 points of reputation yet, sorry for this.

Comment: you mean you found the answer and cannot respond for yourself?

Answer (score 3):

The widget is smaller on ICS because Android 4.0 or later will automatically create a margin around the widget (see also [Android developers API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout)). The solution is create two xml files; one for ICS or later with no extra margins and one for older Android versions with an extra margin.

**res/values/dimens.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="widget_margin">8dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**res/values-v14/dimens.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="widget_margin">0dp</dimen>  
</resources>
```

Then add `android:layout_margin="@dimen/widget_margin"` to the layout in your widget xml file

However, phones with (some versions of?) Samsungs Touchwiz Launcher won't apply the automatic margin on ICS, so you might want to compensate for that also. More info about this in this question: [Widget margins not applied on ICS phone with TouchWiz launcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13121009/741249)